# Sklearn predict python3.5

Tags: python-3.x

I am training a Logistic Regression model using sklearn LogisticRegression.
I am getting a TypeError when trying to predict for the test set.

**CODE:**

```
test_features=test[["Sex","Age","Pclass","Fare","Embarked"]].values
myprediction=myfit2.predict(test_features)
```

**ERROR:**

> float() argument must be a string or a number

I've checked the syntax a few times.Could this be because I'm using Python 3.5. Because this seems to work fine on python 2.7. Would greatly appreciate help to resolve this error.

Comment: can you upload the test dataset? also, do you have any NaN or strings in this test dataset?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data    I've imputed all NaNs and replaced all categorical variables with strings, with integers before feeding it to the predict function

Comment: The problem is that you use "sex" that contains strings and not numbers. the predict() function takes as input a dataset with numbers only. You need to transform "sex" to binary like 1 for males and 0 for females

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the data contain NaN:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nanmean
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

train = pd.read_csv("train.csv") 
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

test["Sex"][test["Sex"]=="male"]=0
test["Sex"][test["Sex"]=="female"]=1
test["Embarked"][test["Embarked"]=='S']=0
test["Embarked"][test["Embarked"]=='C']=1
test["Embarked"][test["Embarked"]=='Q']=2

train["Sex"][train["Sex"]=="male"]=0
train["Sex"][train["Sex"]=="female"]=1
train["Embarked"][train["Embarked"]=='S']=0
train["Embarked"][train["Embarked"]=='C']=1
train["Embarked"][train["Embarked"]=='Q']=2

nan_mean_age = nanmean(test.iloc[:,4])
test = test.fillna(value = nan_mean_age)

nan_mean_age2 = nanmean(train.iloc[:,5])
train = train.fillna(value = nan_mean_age2)

train_features=train[["Sex","Age","Pclass","Fare","Embarked"]].values
test_features=test[["Sex","Age","Pclass","Fare","Embarked"]].values

train_features = np.asarray(train_features)
test_features = np.asarray(test_features)

lg = LogisticRegression()
#define your target variable y and then fit
y_train = train.iloc[:,1]

lg.fit(train_features,y_train)
lg.predict(test_features)
```

result:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Something like this should work fine

Comment: Already did that the first time                                                         **code:**                                       
test["Sex"][test["Sex"]=="male"]=0
test["Sex"][test["Sex"]=="female"]=1
test["Embarked"][test["Embarked"]=='S']=0
test["Embarked"][test["Embarked"]=='C']=1
test["Embarked"][test["Embarked"]=='Q']=2                                                    And the same for the train set as well

Comment: @PoojaRavichandran see my new solution. You need to replace the Nan

Comment: I did replace all NaN's with the mean of the Age.

Comment: @PoojaRavichandran I just posted an example. This works and predicts the Survived variable.

Comment: Cool! This works fine. I used numpy.mean() to fill the NaNs. Replacing that with nanmean() somehow solved the problem. Wonder why though!?  I greatly appreciate you taking time out to help me resolve this. Thanks a lot!